# Is there a difference in physical pixel density on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application, I've found that if I hardcode a view height of 10 pixels, the physical height varies slightly between the iPhone 4S and iPhone 5. On the iPhone 5, it physically looks a little shorter. I know that both are supposed to be 326 PPI displays.

On Android, we have have devices with different physical pixel densities. Therefore a view with a height of 10 px will look shorter on a device with a higher pixel density than one with a lower density. To solve this problem, Android provides DIP (Density Independent Pixels).

Am I doing something wrong in my code to produce these views of different heights, or is there a way in iOS to account for different pixel densities?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is basically about how to determine, if the device is an iPhone 5, that you can use the following macro:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Then branch in your code:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
... handle big screen ...
} else {
... handle small screen ...
}
```

Comment: SAE actually  my question is does iphone 4s and iphone 5 have same pixel density?As I mentioned sometime same 10 px distance appear different. Is this my code fault or any thing else?

Comment: They are the same (326ppi), so it must be something other; maybe an auto-layout constraint, that alters the display of the image or whatever your are displaying.